# How to set the errorbars in a different color from the plot in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, plotting

When making a plot in Matlab using `errorbar(...)` the color of the error bars is the same as the plot. How do I set them to be in a different color?

I tried looking for a way to do it in here:

https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.errorbar-properties.html

https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/errorbar.html

But I couldn't find it.

Comment: This question seems to be about programming and not computational science, as such it would be better suited for Matlab Q&A or StackOverflow.

Comment: @nicoguaro very well, is there a way to transfer it there or I have to repost it there?

Comment: I will migrate it tomorrow to StackOverflow.

Comment: @nicoguaro I can't do it myself? If so, I can just repost it there then.

Comment: @nicoguaro I reposted the question there, so no need to transfer it.